# How to implement a text editor in a browser?

Tags: text-editor, web-browser

This is purely an exercise in self improvement and education.I am trying to implement an extension for a vi-like text editor within a browser. Can anyone give any advice or pointers as to where and how I should start?

Comment: what type of editor are you looking?

Comment: With the lack of research, effort, and code, this question would be unsuitable for Stack Overflow in its current state.

Comment: @ElYusubov,,,just a simple vi-like text editor

Comment: A browser\text editor is the future! I'm searching for this but I think we should desing a new Browser for do that plugin extension are quite limited... Great qestion!

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking to implement a code editor in the browser it's worth looking at the [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) and the [Ajax ACE](http://ace.ajax.org/) projects. ACE is more fully featured, CodeMirror is lighter weight.

If nothing else, they should demonstrate that doing this well is a far from trivial job!

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:** There are number of **open-source text editors** in the market. I would grab one and look at their code base. Improve it if you can, and share back with community.

For example, if you are using a CMS based framework system like Joomla, you may look at variety of  [**editor tools here**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/tools/editors-tools).

You may also look and select from variety of jQuery based text-editors from - [**10 jQuery and non-jQuery javascript Rich Text Editors**](http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors)

Answer (score 0):

Writing an editor to run inside a browser is not that different.

Use Javascript. Use a `<div>` to render your buffer; when you update its contents or alter styles of elements inside it, the browser will repaint it for you. Quite probably, in a line-oriented vi-like editor it's convenient to have every line in a separate nested `div`, too.

Use `onkeydown`, `onclick` and other such event handlers to react on user actions.

The rest is up to you.